# Android - Как спрятать VIew который берется из include?

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это код где установлен include:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="com.eranewgames.vkdownloader.fragments.GroupFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recView"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<include layout="@layout/loading_progress"/>
```

Сам `loading_progress`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

```
public class RestVkRequest {
    private Context context;
    private View viewProgress;

    public RestVkRequest(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        viewProgress= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.loading_progress,null);
        viewProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void getVkGroups(){
        VKRequest vkRequest= new VKRequest("groups.get", VKParameters.from("extended",1));
        vkRequest.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                super.onComplete(response);
                viewProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                GroupsModel groupsModel=new Gson().fromJson(response.responseString,GroupsModel.class);
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventMessage(EventName.RESPONSE_GROUP,groupsModel));
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                super.onError(error);
                viewProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Как видно на картинке, `setVISIBLE` не работает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Не к той view обращаетесь. Нужно задать id ConstraintLayout'у в loading_progress.xml и достать его с помощью `findViewByID()`.

Comment: @woesss, Да не работает блин!

Comment: Да, блин, покажите как у Вас не работает))) Код в вопросе неправильный - LayoutInflater создаёт новую вью и отдаёт ссылку на неё, а не на ту, что отображается на экране - поэтому Вы и не можете ею управлять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    >> android:id="@+id/loadingLayout" <<

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

и в коде loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE) когда надо. Только не забыть забиндить перед этим (через ButterKnife, например, или по-старинке через findViewById

Comment: Все равно не работает.

Comment: Тогда добавьте параметр самому <include... типа того. У меня вёрстка в ConstraintLayout, так что надо изменить на свой вариант.

Comment: `<include layout="@layout/holder_loading" android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/layoutLoadingHolder"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>`